# ionic back button does not change text dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

After setting back button text using config,
it does not reflect right away in nav bar.
Have to pop and push the page again.

**playground:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/backbuttonbug.
you can see in contact page,
setting back button text does not reflect in self page and even in other nav stack

**code:**
previous page:

```
export class AboutPage {  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  contact() {  
    this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);   
  }   
}
```

Next page:

```
export class ContactPage {  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public config: Config) {}

  toChinese() {
    this.config.set("backButtonText", '返回');
  }

  toEnglish() {
    this.config.set("backButtonText", 'back');
  }
}

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Contact
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <button ion-button (tap)="toChinese()">toChinese</button>
  <button ion-button (tap)="toEnglish()">toEnglish</button>
</ion-content>
```

I suspect this is a bug and have opened a issue:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/976.
and find another issue similar:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7043

is that a ionic bug / my program bug?
hope to see advice

Comment: Please add a [mcve] here and not an external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added any code so I'm not 100% sure of what you've tried already but try this:

```
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

...

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.viewCtrl.setBackButtonText('Some dynamic button text');
  }
```

**Edit**

Sorry didn't see your Stackblitz example, this works:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Config, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public config: Config, 
    private viewCtrl: ViewController) {

  }

  toChinese() {
    this.viewCtrl.setBackButtonText('返回');
  }

  toEnglish() {
    this.viewCtrl.setBackButtonText('Back');
  }

}
```

Comment: Still not understand why not view controller's back button text watches ionic config. But for the case, it solves the problem

Comment: Perhaps it's because updating the config does not trigger the Angular change detection? I'm not sure I dealt with this same thing a few weeks ago :-)